# Error 405: Request method 'POST' not supported - Spring Security Java Config

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using Spring MVC (3.2.2.RELEASE) and Spring Security (3.2.2.RELEASE).

I'm trying to do a basic login using spring security, but every time I receive an exception 'HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported'. I already tried searching for similar issues but I was not able to find any solutions.

Following is my code:

login.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
</head>
<body>
    <c:if test="${not empty error}">
                <div>
                    <p style="color: red;">${error}</p>
                </div>
        </c:if>

        <c:if test="${not empty message}">
                <div>
                    <p style="color: red;">${message}</p>
                </div>
        </c:if>

        <c:url var="loginUrl" value="/login" />
        <form action="${loginUrl}" method="post">
            <div>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="username">Email</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Enter Name" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="password">Password</label></td>
                        <td><input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password" required></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>

            <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />

            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Log In">
            </div>
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

SecurityConfig.java

```
package com.bitacora.config;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/bitacora")
            .failureUrl("/login?error")
            .usernameParameter("nombre").passwordParameter("password")
            .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout").permitAll()
            .and()
        .csrf();    
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("123").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
    }
}
```

MvcWebApplicationInitializer.java

```
package com.it2.config.core;

public class MvcWebApplicationInitializer extends
        AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { SecurityConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }
}
```

SecurityWebApplicationInitializer.java

```
package com.bitacora.config.core;

public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends
        AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

    public SecurityWebApplicationInitializer() {
        super(SecurityConfig.class);
    }

}
```

LoginController.java

```
package com.bitacora.controller;

@Controller
public class LoginController extends HttpServlet {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView loginPage(@RequestParam(value = "error",required = false) String error) {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        if (error != null) {
            model.addObject("error", "Invalid Email OR Password");
        }

        model.setViewName("login");
        return model;
    }
}
```

bitacora-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.bitacora" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/img/**" location="/img/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <import resource="classpath://Spring.xml"/>

</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <display-name>BitacoraWEB</display-name>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>bitacora</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>bitacora</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: you got 405 after log in or before?

Comment: Can you make a minimal config/setup of your question? That helps us see the problem, and you to debug it..

Comment: Sure, I changed the code as per your suggestion and I have the same error

Comment: Xeor as you can see in this document it's the minimal configuration for test Spring Security .. .docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/

Answer (score 0):

Because your service(Controller) login operation is a get operation but your UI (view) is sending a post request

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

you should change this to

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

keep your UI (View) as is ( which is with method="post")

```
<form:form id="loginForm" method="post" action="${loginUrl}"
            modelAttribute="loginBean">
```

Comment: OK, We will supose I added, But now what happens, I am not getting the exception, but credentials are not matched with spring security and I am getting redirected to the bitacora page. What I want to do is once I enter credentials, if the credentials are correct I should get redirected to the bitacora page and if credentials are false I should stay on login page with error message. Sorry, I am newbie to spring security so not getting it. Thanks

Comment: you may need to use inMemoryAuthentication from this page...http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/jc.html. Read it well

Comment: As can you see in my code I'm already have all of the configuration/setup that is in the page you mention, for this reason I assume I don't need the POST operation, because in this documentation say: is enough with the .inMemoryAuthentication() and .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/bitacora") configuration the problem is for some reason the FORM is not find this configuration.

Comment: I don't think you understand the difference between GET and POST. You should read about it. You don't login on a GET operation. Read bro

Answer (score -1):

You are posting your login information to `/login`, but the default login processing URL in Spring Security **3.2** is `/j_spring_security_check`.

Change in your form:

```
<c:url var="loginUrl" value="/j_spring_security_check" />
```

*Or* set login processing URL explicit:

```
.formLogin()
    .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
    ...
```